# nth-child(odd) y nth-child(even) no me funcionan en VS Studio

Tags: html, css, vscode

que tal? hace poco he tenido este problema en el cual al querer poner el comando "nth-child" lo toma como valido en varias funciones salvo en esta. Saben a que se puede deber ese error? lo he probado tanto con html como con CSS. aquí el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="grido.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Erick__16 </title>

    <style>
      .prueba > div:nth-last-child(odd){
        background: blue;
      }
      .prueba > div:nth-child(even){
        background: red;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="prueba">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Provident assumenda adipisci ex tempore facere culpa ducimus, nihil veritatis, vero tenetur ipsum vel voluptatum illo neque, dicta quasi in! Possimus, deserunt!
    </div>

    <div class="prueba"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestiae nostrum corrupti error in magnam quia tenetur praesentium perspiciatis voluptas, autem facere deleniti! Sit error tempora impedit quibusdam, labore officia quam.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ayudaría nos compartas que regla de selección tratas de armar

Answer (score 0):

espero ayudarte.

Me fijé que en el CSS lo que estas haciendo es referirte a todos los elementos `div` que sean hijos de la clase CSS `.prueba`, y en el html como no existe el esa estructura pues no hace nada, lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente.

Podrías referirte directamente a los elementos con la clase CSS `.prueba`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="grido.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <title>Pruebas</title>
 <style>
  .prueba:nth-child(even) {
   background: red;
  }

  .prueba:nth-last-child(odd) {
   background: blue;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="prueba">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Provident assumenda adipisci ex tempore facere culpa ducimus, nihil veritatis, vero tenetur ipsum vel voluptatum illo neque, dicta quasi in! Possimus, deserunt!
 </div>
 <div class="prueba">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestiae nostrum corrupti error in magnam quia tenetur praesentium perspiciatis voluptas, autem facere deleniti! Sit error tempora impedit quibusdam, labore officia quam.
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Podrías referirte a los hijos que tengan la clase CSS `.prueba`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="grido.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <title>Pruebas</title>
 <style>
  .prueba p:nth-child(even) {
   background: red;
  }

  .prueba p:nth-last-child(odd) {
   background: blue;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="prueba">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Provident assumenda adipisci ex tempore facere culpa ducimus, nihil veritatis, vero tenetur ipsum vel voluptatum illo neque, dicta quasi in! Possimus, deserunt!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestiae nostrum corrupti error in magnam quia tenetur praesentium perspiciatis voluptas, autem facere deleniti! Sit error tempora impedit quibusdam, labore officia quam.</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias Jonas! es la solucion que mas logica me parece pasa que justo vi un tutorial que hacia todo en html y lo estaba copiando. pero si, cuando he probado como decias me ha funcionado. muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como su nombre lo indica la pseudo-clase nth-child es usada para seleccionar los hijos de un elemento html así como lo explican en MDN tendría la forma

```
.selector-padre .selector-hijo:nth-(child o last-child){ regla css }
```

en tu caso el elemento con el selector `.prueba` no tiene ningun hijo en su estructura css por tal motivo el selector `div:nth-*`  no puede encontrar el elemento al cual aplicar las reglas css.

analizando tu codigo creo que lo que tratas de hacer es colorear el primer div `azul` y el segundo div `rojo` lo cual puedes lograr con el siguiente snippet en el cual cambie el `css` para seleccionar el `body` como padre y `.prueba` como los selectores hijos

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="grido.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <title>Erick__16 </title>
<style> 
body > .prueba:nth-last-child(odd){ 
 background: blue; 
}
body > .prueba:nth-child(even){ 
 background: red; 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body>
<div class="prueba"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Provident assumenda adipisci ex tempore facere culpa ducimus, nihil veritatis, vero tenetur ipsum vel voluptatum illo neque, dicta quasi in! Possimus, deserunt! </div>
<div class="prueba"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestiae nostrum corrupti error in magnam quia tenetur praesentium perspiciatis voluptas, autem facere deleniti! Sit error tempora impedit quibusdam, labore officia quam. 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En este caso esa pseudo clase elegirá del último elemento había atrás solo los pares es decir de forma inversa

Comment: eso era! muchas gracias! al final no estaba captando el tema de la parentalidad entre funciones pero me lo has clarificado